# Scifi short story of a woman who meets her husband's parents, but the husband and his father turn out to be monsters

Tags: story-identification

The woman meets her in-laws, and the mother-in-law seems crazy at first. Then the mother-in-law slowly shows the girl that the two guys, the husband and father-in-law, are monsters or aliens or something. They go out into the woods and find...I think it was a nest? or something like that.

They go back to the in-law's house. It doesn't end happily.

That's all I remember. It was a sad creepy story and I really want to read it again.

Comment: Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. Skye's father and husbands are monsters..

Comment: No, sorry, it's not Agents of SHIELD. It was an old short story.

Comment: Can you give us any idea how old "old" is?

Comment: @Mr Lister Late 90s, it's not that old apparently! Will Feldman found it and linked to the full text below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe **The Sloan Men**, by David Nickle?  The full text is [here](https://sites.google.com/site/davidnickle/thesloanmen).  I haven't read it, but I did see the episode of [The Hunger](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0608334/) television series adapted from it in 1997.  In the adaptation, the husband and father-in-law can wield some sort of mind-control over their wives, forcing them to do things that shock and alienate their families without realizing anything is out of the ordinary.

Comment: This is the one! Thanks for finding it!